# Can't get the complete address while uploading a file

Tags: html

I want to send the mail as an attachment from HTML pages to mail server, but whenever I upload  any file from HTML page, I'm not getting its complete address. I'm just getting its end name. How can I enable my HTML page to track down the complete address of my file? Do I have to do anything special for it?

Answer (score 5):

You are not able to get the full path of the uploaded file. That is a security risk that browsers have been clamping down as of late.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you refer to uploading a file in a HTML form.

The filename you receive may or may not contain the full path, depending on your web browser.
For example, there are differences between uploading from Firefox as opposed to Internet Explorer.