# How to create a browsing button by which I can select any path of the system i.e. C:\Program Files\.. and get it into a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I just want to write html for a browsing button by which I can only select the location of a particular folder or drive i.e. c:\abc\def.

However, I tried `<input type=file />` but it is not I want but in same way.

Strictly, I just want only the folder path and after selecting it,I need to write it in a textbox. I think it can be done the same way  as `<input type=file />` but for the folders.

And also I don't wanna use JPanals (swing/applets).

Any idea on this? Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found many same type of queries but din't find any solution on this place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to resolve the C:\fakepath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

Comment: Didn't you find a vast number of answers saying "this is impossibe"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not posible to get a path of the file via web for security reasons.

Comment: How can I get it in intranet level (on local server)?

Comment: @Moksh - You can't. Internets are webs. File inputs are designed to provide access to files, not information about the user's file system.

Comment: I've tried this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676070/input-type-file-ie-gives-full-path-ff-gives-only-filename-or-directory-bro

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cant do that.

There is an "accept" attribute on file input controls, you can apply any filters via that. 
However, this accept is ignored by many browsers, the mime type of the files work. 
I am not sure if there is a universal mime-type for folders.

i.e.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

that should show you a list of images only in any directory. This is not an answer, but a suggestion that may help you look further into it.

You may be able to put something together using Java or Flash (e.g. using SWFUpload as a basis).

Comment: Thanks. As far as I searched, I found no but I managed to select any file on particular location and from that I captured the path. I know it is irritating but not blocking the funtionality.