# javascript code for getting the value of <input type=file> returns only the filename in firefox

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [<input type='file'> IE Gives full path, FF gives only filename (or directory browse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676070/input-type-file-ie-gives-full-path-ff-gives-only-filename-or-directory-bro)
>   [how to resolve the C:\fakepath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851595/how-to-resolve-the-c-fakepath)

the getImage() function returns the correct full path of the file selected in the  tag in IE .. But it returns only the filename in firefox.. Please do help. I need the full path name in all browsers..

```
getImage()  {
    var location=document.getElementbyId("photo").value;
}

<body>
    <input type=file; id=photo;>
</body>
```

Comment: You most likely will not able to do this as its a security risk.

Comment: What could you possibly need it for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer implementations of browsers don't give you access to the full filenames. You'll just have to deal with it...