# Selecting folder path using input type file

Tags: php, html

I have a problem in PHP. I am using `<input type=file>` to get the file name from the user. 
Basically I want to store the just folder path and not the file, so that when I display the path using hyperlink, the user can open the directory.

But using `<input type=file>` the user has to select a file then only the file textbox will get filled. Now I want to strip off the last part of the filename.

How do I do this ? Or is there a better way to solve this problem?

EDIT:

I am using something like this in say a file named 1.html:

```
<form method="post" action="update.php">
    <input type="file" name="attachment" id="attachment"></td> </tr>
 </form>
```

Now, in update.php I am using something like this:

```
$logpath1=$_POST['attachment'];
```

Basically I am getting the file name in $logpath1 that user selects.
But the thing is input type = file will only work for files and not folders.

So, how do I strip the filename from the path?

Example: if user selects,

```
C:\Documents and Settings\myusee\Desktop\new 2.cpp
```

I want to strip off `new 2.cpp`.

I am not sure how can I use explode. Moreover I am running on [XAMPP Lite](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#646).

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676035/cant-get-the-complete-address-while-uploading-a-file (you can't — file inputs are there to upload files, not information about the visitor's file system)

Comment: I am not taking about file system. I am just using the filename that user selects.

Comment: the path name is information about the file system structure.

Comment: I agree with David Dorward, even after the rewrite. You can't do this server side, only the file's contents are passed along with it's file name only.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

You might be able to get this information from the DOM however after they have selected a file, and from there parse the data into another field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this another way, put a hidden field `<input type="hidden" id="something" name="something" />` and use jQuery (JavaScript) to select the value of the file input box and put it into hidden field before submission and after submission you will have a whole path, I don't know if it works but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers suppress accessing the path info (or any other part of a file input box) for security reasons. With normal file inputs, this can not be done. *Maybe* one of the Flash-based uploading plugins like swfbox allow presetting a directory.

Answer (score 0):

1) **ANY** information about the clients file structure directory path is a security risk. 
POST submits, JavaScript, Flash, Java applications or any other web-based method that has the ability to do this is an exploit.  I would doubt Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari, Opera, or any other browser is going to allow you to do this. If a method is found - a later version most likely will patch this exploit and your code will be rendered useless.

2) If you want to instead display a directory of your *server directory*, you can use this PHP code to get the full path to the temp directory where the uploaded file is stored.

```
$temp_path=$_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
```

However, this would be a security risk for your *SERVER*. Also, the temp path is normally denied access from the web.  Normally, only the PHP interpreter can access this.

Usually, once a file is uploaded, if it is valid, it can be moved this way:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'], $the_directory_i_want);
```

But since `$the_directory_i_want` is a variable *you* set, you would already know this.

It sort of sounds like you are trying to use [WAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAMP) and PHP as a local file utility of some sort.  If that is the case, PHP may not be a good solution. You may instead want to look at creating an [`.HTA application`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application).