# How to save selected image in specific folder using <input type="file">

Tags: php, html

I am selecting an image through  i am getting name of a image. now i want to save that image in specific folder.
here is my html code for photo_upload.php below:-

```html
 <html>
    <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>enter name :</label>
    <input type="text" name="txt" /><br><br>
    <label>Add your file here :</label>
    <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and here is code for upload.php

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "hello to uploadprocessor page";
$name=$_REQUEST['txt'];
$image=$_REQUEST['upload'];
echo "<br><br> $name <br> $image";

$target_dir = "/var/www/html/php_example/photo_upload prg/new photos      folder/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["$image"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;

if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["$image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["tmp_name"]["name"]). " has been  uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting folder path using input type file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763658/selecting-folder-path-using-input-type-file)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the onclick attribute on your button:

Try this: gotten from [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

The image path would be where you save it, depending on the name of the folder

Answer (score 0):

```
$tmp_path = $_FILES['txtImage']['tmp_name'];

$dest_path = path_where_in_your_server_you_want_this_image_to_be_moved.$_FILES['textImage']['name']; (eg: 'images/'.$_FILES['name'])

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_path,$dest_path)){ //this will move the file from tmp   location in server to the destination you provide in the second parameter

$sql = "INSERT INTO tblquestions (q_category, q_question, q_image, q_correct, q_answer2,  q_answer3, q_answer4) VALUES ('$_POST[txtCategory]','$_POST[txtQuestion]','$dest_path','$_POST[txtCorrect]','$_POST[txtChoice2]','$_POST[txtChoice3]','$_POST[txtChoice4]')";

}else{

 echo "Image could not be uploaded"

}
```

Comment: do not forget to clean the input before posting it. mysqli_real_escape_string is an option