# Information for security on website for select image files

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using wordpress with a listings theme.
I want that users when upload an image for any listings don't select any image that they want from their PC but select an image from a specific folder inside the themes files. Reson is that users in my old website upload too much xxx images and I'm bored to check every day.

Ex. wp-content/themes/mytheme/imagefolder

At the moment I'm stuck because I'm not able to do that but I found this article that seems to be useful for me.

[Selecting folder path using input type file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763658/selecting-folder-path-using-input-type-file)

Before I spend hours again, is this method dangerous?

Thanks

Comment: So, you want users to pick from a predefined set of images that you determine? If so, then in general scanning a folder for files should be safe as long as you don't ask the user for any opinion on the folder, they just get "which of these 5 images do you want to use". When you store your data, be careful about blindly storing file names. Instead, if the user picks "image 5", determine what that image's name is on disk, or, just store "pre-set-image-5" or similar in the database.

Comment: _"but I found this article that seems to be useful for me"_ - it isn't. That's about trying to get a folder path _from the client_. You want the user to select files from within a folder _on the server_.