# What is Best way to obtain filename for HTML FILE Uploading on forms?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to obtain the String for the file that is being uploaded from forms to store in the database.

I am using the usual form input file element

```
 input type="file" name="some_name"
```

I found a couple JS scripts that allow me to do useless things like display the string in a dialog box, etc.

I need this as an element on the request object or as a hidden field on my page when the form is posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="some_name"
     onchange="document.getElementById('hidden_file').value = this.value;" />

    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_file" value="" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I believe that will work in all browsers if you simply want to store the filename, [and not the full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676035/cant-get-the-complete-address-while-uploading-a-file).

Answer (score 1):

You won't get a very useful value.  Some browsers will only give you the final name part of the file path, while IE will give you a path with a bogus directory name.

I *think* that the "safe" fragment of the file  name should already be passed in to you as part of the part header in the multipart post body.