# browsing to a file on button click in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, directory-browsing

I want to browse to folder on button click and select a file in that folder. When user selects a particular file. I want to retrieve the folder path and size of that file ?

How can i do that in asp.net with c#

BTW i'm using vs2008.

Please help me

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the FileUpload control instead of a Button? http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/

> Using FileUpload control, it will accept file uploads from users and is extremely easy. With the FileUpload control, it can be done with a small amount of lines of code, as you will see in the following example. However, please notice that there are security concerns to to consider when accepting files from users!

Comment: @Muhammad I don't want to upload a file. I just want to get the file path and size of the file that i select in the folder. I don't know how to do that. Can you please help me with that ? Thanks in anticipation

Comment: @user653622 without file uploader control u cant do that

Comment: @Govind i got it !! Thanks for the advice though !!

Comment: There is one way if you really want to show Button to user, You can put Button control on Fileupload Control (Handle this in HTML), You have to handle manually using Javascript. I did this in one project, But I don't have code right now. That's in my office.

Comment: If you need I will email to you tomorrow. You have to provide me your email.

Comment: @Muhammad ok i will go with file upload control. How can i get the filesize and filepath after i upload the file ?

Comment: FileUpload1.FileContent.Length //File Size
        FileUpload1.FileName //

Comment: @Muhammad i was telling to user653622. i know this trick I have code also in this take both button and file uploader in two div , set position absolute of both , set opacity of uploader to zero , set z index more then button of uploader when user click on button but actually click will perform on fileuploader .

Comment: @Muhammad I'm not getting the full path of the file that i'm upload i'm only getting the file name thats it. I want to get the full path, to be more specific like this : C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Software_Components\file_Name.exe . How can i get the full path ?

Comment: sure, I will send you code tomorrow. You don't need to know full path. As you must store at your end and I hope you don't want to track user path.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control to let user browse to the file, select it and upload it.  Unfortunately, there is no way to retrieve the file size until the file is uploaded (without using Silverlight or other third-party browser components).  Once the file is uploaded, you can retrieve file size via the [ContentLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.contentlength.aspx) property.

Comment: how can i get the filepath of the selected file ??

Comment: I'm not sure you can get the path either.  Check this out:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676035/cant-get-the-complete-address-while-uploading-a-file

Comment: Why do you need the client file path?  You have the path of the file that you saved in the server...