# Obtaining the absolute path of a file selected with a HTML file chooser button using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a small Java application with a web interface using Javafx (with a WebView component).
I am wondering how can I know with JavaScript the absolute path of a file selected with a file chooser in HTML, so I can pass that path to my Java application.

Using JQuery, I tried with this:

```
var completeFileName = $('#button_id').val();
```

but this is returning the name of the file only, not its complete path.

If this is not possible I will have to add a Java file chooser in the javafx stage, but it will be a pity since all the interface components of my application are in html and I wanted to keep it like that.

Comment: JavaScript runs in a sandbox. It can not know the physical path of the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get the complete address while uploading a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676035/cant-get-the-complete-address-while-uploading-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in html 4 its not going to happen, even in HTML 5 i don think you can get anny detailed info about the clients file system.

random google result about this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: For security reasons, the browser only lets you retrieve the file name. JavaScript will not return the full path.